# Create a dynamic submenu in dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have reasons for rescheduling job and also sub-reason under a reason. I want that on selecting the reason, its sub-reason should appear. How do I do that?

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled="disable" selected="selected">
      Select Reason 
  </option>
  <option ng-repeat="reasons in Resonse_schedule ">
     {{reasons.reasons}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Provide an example of your model and html structure

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-options

AngularJS provides a directive ng-options to dynamically list down the options

```
  <select ng-options="reason.reason as reason.reason for reason in Resonse_schedule">
         <option value="" selected disabled >Select Reason</option>

   </select>
```

I would suggest you to go through the documentation of ngOptions to understand it better

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  <select ng-model="reasonVar" ng-options="reason as reason.name for reason in Resonse_schedule">
  <option value="" disabled="disable" selected="selected">Select Reason 
  </option>
  </select>

  <select ng-model="reasonSelected">
   <option ng-repeat="subReason in reasonVar.subReasons" value="subReason.name">
     {{subReason.name}}
   </option>
  </select>
```

Where `reasonVar` is the selected value from the `Resonse_schedule` list.

Here's a working example for this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/35122/

And here's more complicated one:
http://jsfiddle.net/miparnisari/u50hgn5a/